# Day option not refresh when Month is change

Tags: jquery

Here my Month select option HTML:

```
<select id="cmbMonth" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <option value="--" selected="selected">--</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Day select option HTML:

```
<select id="cmbDay" style="margin-right:20px;">
        <option value="--" selected="selected">--</option>
</select>
```

Here is my jQuery to control the the YEAR, MONTH, and DATE:

```
    //Get Year, Month, and Day
    function daysInMonth(month,year) {
        var dd = new Date(year, month, 0);
        return dd.getDate();
    }

    function setDayDrop(dyear, dmonth, dday) {
        var year = dyear.options[dyear.selectedIndex].value;
        var month = dmonth.options[dmonth.selectedIndex].value;
        var day = dday.options[dday.selectedIndex].value;

        if (day == '--') {
            var days = (year == '--' || month == '--')
                ? 31 : daysInMonth(month,year);
            dday.options.length = 0;
            dday.options[dday.options.length] = new Option('--','--');
            for (var i = 1; i <= days; i++)
                dday.options[dday.options.length] = new Option(i,i);
        }
    }

    function setDay() {
        var year = document.getElementById('cmbYear');
        var month = document.getElementById('cmbMonth');
        var day = document.getElementById('cmbDay');
        setDayDrop(year,month,day);
    }

$('#cmbMonth').change(function() {
    setDay();
});
```

This code work fine for refresh the cmbDay when month is change in preload stage.

The problem is when user selected a day, and change the month again, day option is not refresh and keep on previous month of date.

Comment: You're mixing native JS and jQuery — is there a reason why?

Comment: @mplungjan But when date is clicked and again you change the month, date is not refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because you have only changed the values when your day is "--". but when it is already present this condition fails and there is nothing to execute.

```
 if (day == '--') // for first time
{
    // code to generate days for the selected month
}
else // when day is already present
{
   // code to generate days for the selected month
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me if I remove the if, reset the day and add the change to both year and month

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vE59P/)

```
function setDayDrop(dyear, dmonth, dday) {
    var year = dyear.options[dyear.selectedIndex].value;
    var month = dmonth.options[dmonth.selectedIndex].value;
    var days = (year == '--' || month == '--') ? 31 : daysInMonth(month, year);
    dday.options.length = 1; // no need to set this to 0 each time
    for (var i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
      dday.options[dday.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
    }
}

function setDay() {
    var year = document.getElementById('cmbYear');
    var month = document.getElementById('cmbMonth');
    var day = document.getElementById('cmbDay');
    // optional
    // day.selectedIndex=0; 
    setDayDrop(year, month, day);
}
$(function () {
    $('#cmbMonth, #cmbYear').change(function () {
        setDay();
    });
});
```

Comment: you can hide the month and day when year is not chosen and day if month not chosen

Comment: Yes..I implementing the code now. And I also try to make if first index of year is selected, month and day will hide

Comment: I do not have time, but I started with this     var year = $dyear.val();
    $month.toggle(year!="--");
    $day.toggle($month.is(":visible"));
    if ($day.not(":visible")) return;